# How to write contents of a Cairo Image surface into a Gdk Pixbuf?

Tags: gtk, cairo, surface, gdk

I have a canvas(Gdk Drawing Area), which I can draw into it using Cairo, but I need to save contents of my canvas into a buffer which in my case is a Gdk Pixbuf. I want to know if it's possible or not, if there is a better way I would like to know.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We do this in f-spot using a simple copy routine. Not the most elegant solution, but it works:

http://git.gnome.org/browse/f-spot/tree/lib/libfspot/f-pixbuf-utils.c#n170

Comment: link is dead, any way you can post again?